# how to find clients ip address using tcp socket programming in c

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I am trying to develop a TCP server, in that server clients are connecting with the server after the set up the connection. But how do i find the ip address from that connection. Sample codes are given here.

```
int connfd;
int listenfd;
struct sockaddr_in cliaddr;
socklen_t clilen;

connfd = accept(listenfd,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,&clilen);
```

this is not the exact code. But now i need to find the client address as a string.

Comment: Did you think to look up any of the types you're using?

Comment: Sorry i didn't get you.

Comment: I mean: read the documentation for the data types you are using.  There might be a hint there...

Answer (score 6):

`accept()` gives you the client's remote IP address and port number in the `sockaddr_in` struct that it fills in, in the `sin_addr` and `sin_port` struct members, respectively.  Both values are numeric values in network byte order.  You can use a function like `inet_ntoa()` to convert the IP into a human-readible string, and `ntohs()` to convert the port number into an integer whose byte order matches the calling machine so you can work with it more naturally.

Also look at the `getpeername()` and `getsockname()` functions.

Answer (score 2):

cliaddr is the structure variable for of structure sockaddr_in for the client.

cliaddr.sin_addr.s_addr contains the client's IP address.

inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(cliaddr.sin_addr), clientAddr, CLADDR_LEN);   Retrieves the IP address of the client into a string clientAddr.